# Convert from bytes[] to EBCDIC string

Tags: java, string, ibm-mq, mainframe

I am receiving bytes[] from mainframe MQ. This bytes[] I am trying to convert to EBCDIC string. I am using the following and the sytem just hangs. What could be the issue?

```
new String(mqmdAccountingToken,"Cp1047");
```

mqmdAccountingToken is the byte array received from MQ. I feel that the Charset that I have provided is not correct. Is there a way to identify the correct charset to use and then convert?

Comment: What do you mean with “the system just hangs”? If the program doesn’t return try to dump a stack trace, e.g. using `jstack` or `jvisualvm`.

Comment: Ask your support staff/colleagues what CodePage you should be using. If you can look at the content, perhaps you can see something likely-looking.

Answer (score 2):

The MQMD AccountingToken field is made up of both binary values and character values set by the queue manager (default behavior), so you need to treat it as a binary field (i.e. byte[] field) and not a character field.

If you really want to convert it to some character field then convert it to Hex display characters.

Comment: Nice information, but why would the covert "hang". Conversion won't be stopped by source being binary, as all sources for the conversion are binary. Output will be nonsense, but why the hang?

Comment: Presumably, though, you could dump it and then extract the actual character field subsets - having eyeballed the dump.

Comment: Well, he never said what was hanging.  No code snippets, so we can only guess.  The following does work but prints junk because of the binary data: System.out.println(" AccountingToken: " + new String(msg.accountingToken));

Answer (score 1):

Evidently one of the main criticisms of EBCDIC early on was its large number of variants.  You will need to determine, almost certainly outside your program, which variant you have, and use the corresponding character set.  The fact that it is from a "mainframe" and MQ does not identify the character set.  You can see the number of possible sets [at this IBM site](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp_cpgid.html).

Comment: The A in ASCII is American. So there is only one ASCII. However, in practice, the multiple versions is no different between the two is it? So what's your actual point?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear, but I see from re-reading that it may not be.  The OP is using one encoding name to translate ebcdic, but in fact there are many different encodings all called ebcdic.  If you look at the IBM site mentioned, you can see that there are lots of them; if you look at a list of Java encoding names, you will see that there are different encodings for different ebcdic translations.  So perhaps he's just using the wrong one.  And there are, in fact, different encodings called ASCII as well...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should be dealing with MQMD AccountingToken field - you convert it from binary data to hex display characters.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String hex;
for (i=0; i < msg.accountingToken.length; i++)
{
   hex = Integer.toHexString((new Byte(msg.accountingToken[i])).intValue());

   if (hex.length() == 2)
      sb.append(hex);
   else if (hex.length() == 1)
      sb.append("0" + hex);
   else if (hex.length() > 2)
   {
      sb.append(hex.substring(hex.length()-2,hex.length()-1));
      sb.append(hex.substring(hex.length()-1,hex.length()));
   }
}
System.out.println(" AccountingToken: X'" + sb.toString().toUpperCase() + "'");
```